# how to implement shutterstock tiker?

Tags: iphone, ticker

I have tried [MKTikcerView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mktickerview) , [DMScrollingTicker](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dmscrollingticker) and also made a [Custom TickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658616/subsequent-instances-of-a-uiview-subclass-causing-display-error) but , I am not satisfied with that all. All of them when comes to end string displays blank space.They are have not continuous objects displaying.I also use UITableView to show ticker objects by transforming it to horizontal.But there was also a problem that is some of the cells displaying blank.

The main objective is that , I want a ticker view like pull down shutterStock in iphone.It has continuous and updated objects and very smooth scrolling.

screenshot is given below:

[image]

Anyone help me please!
Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add some improvement in my custom tickerView that displays view objects.Here is the files:
[StockTicker.h](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=pXgx0vdg) and [StockTicker.m](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=zsgTFc1d) .By using these files you can create continuous object displaying on tickerView and can update data easily.
You can use these files just like UITableView.It has its delegates to pass numberOfView to display on ticker and view that will display at particular index.

Using its delegates as:

```
#pragma mark- UITickerView delegate method

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsintickerView:(StockTiker *)tickerView
{
        return [objectArray count];
}

- (id)tickerView:(StockTiker*)tickerView cellForRowAtIndex:(int)index
{
        return [objectArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

here objectArray is array of UILabels.

You can download [SampleProject](https://github.com/ipreencekmr/REPOSITORY).